# SetData() not working on Change Event HighCharts Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm looking for a way to dynamically update data in a highcharts pie chart based on the change event on a dropdownlist.  I have seen a couple examples but I am really unable to figure out why I can't get this working.  Here is my whole code, I wrap my stuff inside a function so I can call the function with the Change() event of the dropdownlist, but I get the error of CRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'setData'

```
function showClass(){
    var total = 0;
var options = {
        chart:{type:'pie',
        renderTo: 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Overview1_tcAssetAllocation_body',
              events: {
                load: function(event) {
                $('.highcharts-legend-item').last().append('<br/><div style="width:220px"><hr/> <span style="float:left"> Total </span><span style="float:right">100%</span> </div>')                    
                }
              }
        },
        credits:{enabled: false},
        colors:[
            '#5485BC', '#AA8C30', '#5C9384', '#981A37', '#FCB319',     '#86A033', '#614931', '#00526F', '#594266', '#cb6828', '#aaaaab', '#a89375'
            ],
        title:{text: null},
        tooltip:{
            enabled: true,
            animation: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                animation: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                showInLegend: true,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,                        
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.percentage.toFixed(2) + '%';
                    }
                }                                   
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            width: 220,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            borderWidth: 0,
            useHTML: true,
            labelFormatter: function() {
            total += this.y;
                return '<div style="width:200px"><span style="float:left">' + this.name + '</span><span style="float:right">' + this.y + '%</span></div>';
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Primary',
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            data: [['Domestic Equity', 38.5],['International Equity', 26.85],['Other', 15.70],['Cash and Equivalents', 10.48],['Fixed Income', 8.48]]
        }]
}
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Overview1_AccountList1_ddlAccounts").change(function(){
    var selVal = $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Overview1_AccountList1_ddlAccounts").val();
    if(selVal == '1124042'){
        chart.series[0].setData([['Domestic Equity', 18.5], ['International Equity', 46.85], ['Other', 5.70], ['Cash and Equivalents', 20.48], ['Fixed Income', 8.48]]);                }
});
```

}

is it because i am nested inside another function?  it's jsut that all the fiddles use the document.ready function and it loads properly calling the function in the document.ready() but getting it on the change event is messing with me.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Tahnk you very much,
NickG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong to use object `options` as part of Highcharts API. Find that line: `options.series[0].setData` and change to `chart.series[0].setData()`.  Then remove creating new chart ( you don't need that - chart is already created ).

Comment: thank you for the insight, when i change that line to chart.series[0].setData() I receive the error of Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Make sure that your variable `chart` exists.

Comment: could you possibly edit my code to give me an idea what you mean?  my variable chart is declared when i render the chart with the original options on the line of var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); before the change event code.  Do i re-declare var chart inside the change event and just do var chart = { set new data...... }? sorry i am new to this and i do appreciate your help

Comment: Example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/TEDBG/1/ You had one more issue - argument for setData should be an array of points, not many arguments each as point.

Comment: I still receive the same error, is it because my code is wrapped inside another function that i call on the change event of the dropdown and on the document.ready()?  I didn't know if the change event firing, calling this function, then checking for the change event mattered, but when i debug the JS in IE Dev Tools, it steps into the change event correctly and into the if selVal == '' statement perfect, just doesn't update the data.

Comment: Can I see it live or could you reproduce issue on jsFiddle? My example works fine, maybe your value isn't the same.

Comment: I was calling my showClass() function on the change event of the dropdownlist then calling the dropdownlist change event inside the function again which was causing my error, I took out the showClass() call inside of the change event and it's working perfectly. Thank you very much for your help!! couldn't have done it without you!